# Nesting a Nested Function to Run in Sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, nested

I have three functions that I want to run in sequence (and then repeat, but I'm not even on that yet.) So when the first function displays its content and then leaves, the second function will play afterwards and do the same thing. Then that repeats into the third function. I'm using callbacks to try to achieve this.

This isn't a problem when I'm using only two functions, but when I introduce the third, It renders the first two menu boards, and then the third one comes afterwards, when they should render 1, 2 and then 3.

JavaScript for Reference

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        Board1 = function(callback){
            $('#menu-board .board.one .row').slideDown(800).delay(10000).slideUp(800, function(){
                callback();
            });
        }
        Board2 = function(callback){
            $('#menu-board .board.two .row').slideDown(800).delay(10000).slideUp(800, function(){
                callback();
            });
        }
        Board3 = function(){
            $('#menu-board .board.three .row').slideDown(800).delay(10000).slideUp(800);
        }

        Board1(Board2(Board3)); 

});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Because `Board2(Board3)` will just start `Board2` imediately.

Answer (score 3):

```
Board1(Board2(Board3));
```

is equal to:

```
var res = Board2(Board3);
Board1(res);
```

So it won't act as you expect, it just start to execute `Board2`, and then start `Board1`, so `Board3` is only guranteed to execute after `Board2`, while the order of `Board1` is not relevant to `Board2` and `Board3`.

You can use `.bind` to create a function that calls Board2 with give param Board3 like:

```
Board1(Board2.bind(null, Board3));
```

or just wrap them in another function:

```
Board1(function() {
    Board2(Board3);
});
```

However, if you have too many functions to chain, use the methods above may not be a good idea, then you may create a chainer to do what you want:

```js
// This function will accept a sequnce of functions in array, execute them in order, and call the done callback when all is complete.
var chain = function(sequences, done) {
  // Manage the current index, and total items that would be called.
  var idx = 0, length = sequences.length;
  var caller = function() {
    // When all functions in sequence is called, call final callback to notify user
    // you may have to check if done is a function or not.
    if (idx === length) {
      if (typeof done === 'function') {
        done();
      }
      return;
    }
    // Get the next function to call.
    var currentTarget = sequences[idx];
    // Pass caller to the target function, so when the function completes and call the callback
    // the caller can takeover and start to call next function in sequence.
    currentTarget(caller);
    ++idx;
  };

  caller();
};


// Create some test cases.
var sequence = [], i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // Create some functions that will display some text after 1 sec when it get called.
    sequence[i] = (function(index) {
        return function(cb) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'Index is: ' + index;
                document.body.appendChild(div);
                cb();
            }, 1000);
        };
    }(i));
}

// Demo.
chain(sequence, function() {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("All done."));
});
```

By the `chain` function above, you can now use it as `chain([Board1, Board2, Board3])` and it keeps the codes simple even if you have a sequence of many functions.

PLUS:

From [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)'s document:

> Callback Function
>
> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete.
>   This can be useful for stringing different animations together in
>   sequence. The callback is not sent any arguments, but this is set to
>   the DOM element being animated. If multiple elements are animated, it
>   is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched
>   element, not once for the animation as a whole.
>
> As of jQuery 1.6, the .promise() method can be used in conjunction
>   with the deferred.done() method to execute a single callback for the
>   animation as a whole when all matching elements have completed their
>   animations ( See the example for .promise() ).

So if there's more than 1 element match to animate, the callback in your current function will get called more than once, you may have to rewrite your function with what the doc suggest to

```
 Board1 = function(callback){
     $('#menu-board .board.one .row').slideDown(800).delay(1000).slideUp(800).promise().done(callback);
 }
```

You can see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsadqc4a/) that work as you expect.

Comment: This seems to be on the right path, but when the third board is called, the second board also shows up with it.

Comment: @user1757979 Updated my answer, added the reason why you met that issue and the solution to it, with jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just call the callback function directly in the slideup function.somewhat like this:

```
$('#menu-board .board.one .row').slideDown(800).delay(10000).slideUp(800, callback);
```

let me know if this does not work.

This is the reference for slideup function:

http://api.jquery.com/slideup/